# How to Suppress Security Risk Notices Occuring during HTTPWebRequests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

When I send HTTPWebRequests to certain web sites I get a popup message stating that there us an upspecified Security Risk associated with the site and do I want to continue.  The message does not occur until after the HTTPWebRequest has been retrived and stored as a string (ResponseAsString in the code below).  The HTTPWebrequest retrieves the text of a webpage which is subsequently converted into an IHTMLDocument2 with the code that follows.  The warning occurs on the command -- oDoc.close();   A try-catch block does not yield show an error.  Is there any way to suppress this message?

```
//Creates IHTMLDocument2 frow WebRequest!
private IHTMLDocument2 GetIHTMLDoc2FromString(string ResponseAsString) 
{
   HTMLDocument ProfileHTML = new HTMLDocument(); 
   IHTMLDocument2 oDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)ProfileHTML; 
   oDoc.write(ResponseAsString);
   oDoc.close();
   return oDoc; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any mentionig of HttpWebRequiest in your sample - what makes you think the problem has anything to do with HttpWebRequest but not with the fact that you are trying to create HTML document from some string?

Comment: I didn't see that either but assumed he was using it somewhere, hence my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
 public static bool IgnoreInvalidSSL { get; set; }
    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
    {
        if (IgnoreInvalidSSL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return policyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
        }
    }
```

Then on your httprequest use

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin: I'm not sure how this would be done as the HTTPWebRequest only has a servicepoint property. Also, doesn't this code only tell you if you have an SSLPolicyError? When I visit this website manually using IE, I simply click the yes button (I want to continue) on the potential security alert notification and go on. This clicking of the yes button or it's equivalent is what I want to duplicate with code -- or better still not have the notification come up. After all I'm just automating a manual process I've already determined is OK.

Comment: It isn't a property of HTTPWebRequest (or even WebRequest) it's just a static class.

Comment: Dustin: I'm pretty sure this isn't an SSLPolicyError problem. I've inserted the line ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain,sslPolicyErrors) => true); 
which should cause any SSLPolicyErrors to be ignored.  Any suggestions?